# Generate random numbers that depend on string hash

Tags: java, random, hash

I'm trying to generate `n` random numbers that depend on an input string. It would be a function `generateNumbers(String input)` that generates the same set of numbers for the same input string but entirely different numbers for a slightly different input string.

My question is: Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [may be this can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969733/create-a-uniform-random-number-based-on-a-hash)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to actually generate random numbers, but a unique set of numbers based on a given input string. Or, put another way, a completely numerical hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with nihlon, if what you want is a function f() returning an int such that `f(string1) != f(string2)` for any `string1`, `string2` in some set of strings `S`, then you're looking for a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). 
Obviously, if `S` is the set of all possible strings, there are way more than 2^32, or even 2^64, so no such `f()` can exist returning an `int` or even `long`. Hence, the question is: how is `S` characterized?

Also, are you sure you need unique numbers for different strings? In most problem domains regular hashing is adequate...

Answer (score 0):

As Roberto says, a hash is one way to do this, with a small possibility of two different strings hashing to the same value.  That probability depends on the maximum size of string you allow and the bit-size of the resulting hash number.

You could also use an encryption, but then you would have to limit the string size to one or two blocks of a block cipher.  Two blocks of AES is 32 characters, and will produce a 256 bit number.

Pick the smallest string size you can live with, and the largest hash size/block size you can work with.  A non-cryptographic hash like the [fnv hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) will be faster than a cryptographic hash like [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), but obviously less secure.  You do not say how important security is to you.